# Is lookup in Visual workflow a kind of SOQL?

Tags: soql, flow, visual-workflow, governorlimits

I'm new to visual workflows and while I was creating one I got this question. Does Any lookup (Fast/Record) adds SOQL to the given transaction and may cause governor limit hit? I want to use multiple lookups in my flow and wants to avoid adding additional SOQL. When I browsed the web I couldn't find any specific answer which solves my query. Thanks for the Help in advance!!

Comment: If you search for 'SOQL' in the docs, you will find helpful info too: http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/20/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_vpm_implementation_guide.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short Answer **YES**

Long Answer: All the components/actions add to the governor limits. But the advantage with Flow is: **A new transaction begins each time the user clicks "Next" in a screen, so there are less chances of hitting limits**.  Anyways, here are the limits

- Total **number of SOQL** queries issued : **100 Per Transaction**
  (Record Update, Record Delete, Record Lookup, and Fast Lookup element executions)
- Total **number of records** retrieved by SOQL queries : **50,000 Per Transaction**
  (across all Record Update, Record Delete, Record Lookup, and Fast Lookup elements executed in all interviews in the transaction)
- Total **number of DML** statements issued : **150 Per Transaction**
  (Record Create, Record Update, Record Delete, Fast Create, Fast Update, and Fast Delete executions)
- Total **number of records processed** as a result of DML statements  **10,000 Per Transaction**

Comment: Thanks for the Quick response. Especially for this info "A new transaction begins each time the user clicks "Next" in a screen". I can make better decisions now.